# extjs - center a formPanel on a normal panel

Tags: extjs, centering

I'm using extjs and just trying to solve a simple problem:
I have a form with a fixed width. I want to Center this form within a normal Ext.Panel.
I'm trying to achieve this the 'css-way' - setting the left and right margin to 'auto'.

But this doesn' work, it seems the margins are just ignored.

The Code:

```
var curStateForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title:'test',
    width:300,
    bodyStyle:'margin:5px auto 0 auto',
    items: [edIst, edAdjust, edSumme]
});   


var testPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    width: '100%',
    frame:true,
    items: [curStateForm]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this sample](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)?  Look at the example under "custom layouts / center".

EDIT: In Ext 3, that sample was the way to go. Now in Ext 4, it would be best to use a vbox layout on the outer container with center alignment as shown in [A1rPun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216519/108348).

Comment: Thanks, didn't found that but I think thats what I'm looking for ;)

Comment: This page is very bad, half the code snippets do not work, and they do not represent what is on the screen !

Comment: The example url is no longer valid

Answer (score 17):

This works perfect for me in Ext 4

Use it on any container

```
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Centered Panel',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    }]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    style: {
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto'
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I just did this to a panel

```
listeners: {
    afterlayout : function(container, layout, eOpts) {
    panel.center();
    }
}
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In panel:

```
bodyStyle: "padding: 15px;"  // may also be only padding-left/right
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance, I use this layout:

```
Ext.layout.AbsoluteCenterLayout = Ext.extend(Ext.layout.ContainerLayout, {
    monitorResize:true,
    onLayout : function(ct, target){
        Ext.layout.AbsoluteCenterLayout.superclass.onLayout.call(this, ct, target);
        if(!this.container.collapsed){
            var sz = (Ext.isIE6 && Ext.isStrict && target.dom == document.body) ? target.getViewSize() : target.getStyleSize();
            this.setItemSize(this.activeItem || ct.items.itemAt(0), sz);
        }
    },
    setItemSize : function(item, size){
        if(item && size.height > 0){ // display none?
            formEl = item.getEl();
            var widthCenter = (size.width/2)-(formEl.getWidth()/2);
            var heightCenter = (size.height/2)-(formEl.getHeight()/2);
            formEl.setStyle({
                left: widthCenter+'px',
                top: heightCenter+'px',
                position: 'absolute',
            });
        }
    }
});
Ext.Container.LAYOUTS['absolutecenter'] = Ext.layout.AbsoluteCenterLayout;
```

My form:

```
    Viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    region: 'center',
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'absolutecenter',
                    baseCls: 'x-plain',
                    items:[{
                        id: 'form',
                        formId: 'admin-loginform',
                        xtype: 'form',
                        title: 'Authentication',
                        iconCls: 'admin-wnd-authentication',
                        frame: true,
                        autoHeight: true,
                        width: 270,
                        defaultType: 'textfield',
                        labelAlign: 'right',
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the panel:

```
style: {
    "margin-left": "auto",
            "margin-right": "auto"
       },
```